# subsequent element as attribute in xml using xslt

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

need help in making subsequent element as attribute to preceding element if subsequent element contains the preceding element name using XSLT.

For below example, <**emp**_id> contains the preceding the element name so need to convert this element as attribute to  element. can you anyone help for this?. I tried using subsequent functions in xslt but not working. Thanks in advance.

Sample XML:

```
<root>
    <emp>test</emp>
    <emp_id>1234</emp_id>
    <college>something</college>
</root>
```

Expected out:

```
<root>
    <emp id="1234">test</emp>
    <college>something</college>
</root>
```

Comment: Can it be assumed that every element whose name contains a `_` has a "parent" element whose attribute it should become?

Comment: Yes we can assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the given example, you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[starts-with(name(), name(current()))]" mode="attr"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="attr">
    <xsl:attribute name="{substring-after(name(), '_')}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[preceding-sibling::*[name()=substring-before(name(current()), '_')]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to achieve the expected result.

---

There is probably a more elegant way, but we need to have some more *rules*, not just a single example.

---

### Added:

Assuming that every element whose name contains a `_` has a "parent" element whose attribute it should become, you can start by applying templates to only the "parent" elements (i.e. elements whose name does not contain a '_').

Then use a **key** to collect the "child" elements that need to be converted to attributes.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="atr" match="*" use="substring-before(name(), '_')" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(contains(name(), '_'))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('atr', name())">
            <xsl:attribute name="{substring-after(name(), '_')}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is it possible to check with preceding element name with _ then converting the element to attribute. Ex: <**emp_**id> we need to look for emp_ where emp is preceding element name and _ which is constant.